# Slicing is not working correctly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

**Why the code listed below is not working:**

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(a[1::-1])
```

*This code should print [2,1,9,8,7,6,5,4,3].But it is printing [2,1].Why is this happening?*

Comment: Because you told it to "start from index 1 & go back by 1" - which leads to `[2,1]`

Comment: But I haven't given the stop so it should not print that.It should go back to 9.

Comment: slicing automatically stops when it reaches any end of the list, lists are not circular (no looping back to the other end)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your logic for the code printing [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3] is that is starts at the first index (2), then decrements to print the 0th index (1). Then it sets the index to the last one (index 8 which is 9) and goes back from there. So:

1 -> 0 -> 8 -> 7 -> ... -> 3

However, what happens with list slicing, is the index stops at 0. i.e. it never goes beyond the length of the list, or 0. So it goes like:

1 -> 0

If you want to print [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3] using list slicing, the following code should work:

`print(a[1::-1] + a[:1:-1])`

Here, we add the two lists that go from index 1-0, and from the last index of the list to 1

Answer (score 0):

in step parameter you are giving -1 so it will go from end to start, hence it will printing [2,1]

Answer (score 0):

So, you entered -1 at last. Then python will simply write(print) the words from right to left i.e. 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1.
Now, python will go from +1 i.e. 2 to last integer i.e. 1.